# Can I change/delete records in/from a database view?

Tags: c#, database, winforms

So for convenience purposes I am working with a created view of a few database tables to properly display data from those tables in a datagrid.
Now I want to delete an entry from that datagrid and the database, but when I try it the way I have done it normally, even in this project

```
private void deleteEntry_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CustomerDBEntities db = new CustomerDBEntities();

    int a = (int)dataGridView_Orders.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value;

    VOrders deleteOrder = db.VOrders.Where(x => x.PKOrders == a).First();

    db.VOrders.Remove(deleteOrder);
    db.SaveChanges();

    UpdateOrders();
}
```

but it doesn't work and throws the following exception at me

> `System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException`: "Unable to update the EntitySet 'VOrders' because it has a DefiningQuery and no  element exists in the  element to support the current operation."

Does it just not work this way for Views? I've taken a look around for this exception, but it all just seems to refer to normal tables instead of views and doesn't seem to help.

Comment: A view is generally a way to display several linked tables. When "deleting" a row of a view, how would the system know which row(s) of which table(s) to delete? Maybe you have a left join in your view, then removing a row from the left table would be enough for it not to be displayed anymore, but is it what you'd want? Wouldn't you want to also delete rows in other tables? That's how many questions the system is unable to decide by itself

Comment: @Rafalon Hey, thanks for taking your time! It actually makes a lot of sense now that I think about it.

Edit: Didn't think enter would send my reply. 
The view brings 4 tables together, and I only really want to delete the data out of one of those, as the others have important data for other things in the application aswell.

Comment: Then instead of trying to delete a row from your view, get the corresponding row in the right table, and delete this one. `RightTable deleteOrder = db.RightTable.First(x => x.PKOrders == a);` then `db.RightTable.Remove(deleteOrder);`